# Audio tag set currentTime fails

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

[image: Does anyone know why would this happen in chrome]

So as can be seen on the image when audio is loaded I am trying to set time it always defaults to 0 in chrome.
Works fine in Firefox.

Does anyone know why would this happen in Chrome

Comment: What is the value of `this.paused`?

Comment: its true of course I play it on line 58; I tried to apply time to video that is playing and got the same result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Chrome with wave files. I reported it to Chrome team and now its working as expected. Its not a real answer, but this is what happened.